# setting Default Text inside Yii textarea

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I'm new to Yii and i am facing issues with it. Hope some pros here can help me solve this. I bought a script online and i am editing it to my needs.

I want to have a text area with default texts. Example;

```
Name:
Age:
Sex:
```

what it is generating now:

```
<textarea class="span vertical medium" name="MAccount[accountInfo]" id="MAccount_accountInfo"></textarea>
```

what i want it to generate,or something like this :

```
<textarea class="span vertical medium" name="MAccount[accountInfo]" id="MAccount_accountInfo">Name: <br> Age: <br> Sex:</textarea>
```

something like above. But i only able to produce a textarea with blank/no content.below is my code,it is located inside a worklet.;

```
public function properties() {
    $properties = array(
        'elements' => array(
            'accountInfo' => array(
                'type' => 'textarea',
                'class' => 'span vertical medium',
            ),
            'email' => array(
                'disabled' => true,
                'append' => $this->model()->role == 'unverified' ? $this->t('unverified') : $this->t('verified'),
                'hint' => $this->model()->role == 'unverified' ? $this->resendBtn() : '',
            ),
            wm()->get('project.edit.buttons', array('step' => $this->step, 'projectId' => $this->project->id))->render('tools', array(), true),
        ),
        'model' => $this->model(),
        'class' => 'projectEditForm',
    );

    return $properties;
}
```

Comment: basically with the code, if i edit the class and etc, it would reflect on the generated textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Default values are set in your model, not in your view. So you have to look in your `model/` directory and locate the right model there. There you can add

```
public $accountInfo = "Name:\nAge:\nSex:";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo CHtml::activeTextArea($form,'abc',array('value'=>"12"));?>
$form->abc="Your text goes here"
```

it may help you